# Getting error trying to build Ghostscript 9.0.1 on Macintosh

Tags: macos, build-process, ghostscript

The build fails in the middle with errors of the form

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      _opvp_to_utf8 in gdevopvp.o
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      _opvp_to_utf8 in gdevopvp.o
  "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      _opvp_to_utf8 in gdevopvp.o

I have been unable to find anything via google search that addresses this issue. Would appreciate any insights.

Thanks,
David

Comment: Try to disable the "opvp" device in the top level Makefile -- you'll very likely not need it. (Remove the string *$(DD)opvp.dev* from the line starting `DEVICE_DEVS2=`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you also need to remove the oprp device mention next to the opvp one. I just built it fine using 10.6.7 doing just this.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to modify (OPVP_DEVS='oprp opvp') to (OPVP_DEVS='') in configure file. 
Then, run ./configure, afterwards sudo make.
I tested it just now, it seems work well.